# Apply EffectFactory Effects on CameraPreview

Tags: android, android-camera, lomo-effect

I am trying to make an Android application that lets the user take a picture with lomo effect. The thing is, I want to make the camera preview the image WITH the effect automatically, not take a picture then apply the effect.

I learned how to use CameraPreview on this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html). I also found out about EfectFactory class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html), which has the effect I want. The problem is, I don't know how to apply efectfactory class on a CameraPreview.

I googled this but didn't find the answer I was looking for.

For the code, I am using the same as how my first link provided.

Can anyone help me on this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Hamidreza Samadi Check this library: ly.img.android:photo-editor library

Comment: consider the [Samsung SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#camera)

Answer (score 2):

You can do below thing:

1) Get bitmap from captured image in **GLS Surface** view

and then

2) Apply effects using **Effect Factory** class.

More detail use this [link](http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html).

Comment: I could not do it. :(